# Kinect 2 on Ubuntu 16.04, device not listed in `lsusb`

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, kinect

I'm trying to get a Kinect v2 to run with my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I've already installed `libfreenect2`. To no avail.

`dmesg` shows me the following output upon connecting the Kinect:

```
[ 3541.672526] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3541.802912] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d9
[ 3541.802919] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3541.802924] usb 1-6: Product: NuiSensor Adaptor      
[ 3541.802928] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation  
[ 3541.803672] hub 1-6:1.0: USB hub found
[ 3541.803857] hub 1-6:1.0: 1 port detected
```

`lsusb -t` shows the following devices:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

It seems to me like there's some kernel module, driver, kernel setting or something like this missing that's required to detect all the integrated devices inside the Kinect. The integrated hub seems to be detected but the devices behind it are not detected.

Do you know what I can do to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing all (!) the dependencies (provided in the subfolder of `libfreenect2/depends`) including `libusb` and building `libfreenect` again from scratch (completely wiping the usual cmake `build` subfolder, then again `cmake ..`) it now works.

So, in case you run into the same problem: first make sure you've really installed **all** dependencies and everything shown in `libfreenect2/depends`.